# how to make intent configured for updates(push notfications) in google actions?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, api-ai

I have followed all the steps given on https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates

but when I'm trying to test the conversation send api
[https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send?access_token="My_Access_Token](https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send?access_token=%22My_Access_Token)"

I'm  getting below error:

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": 400,
>           "message": "Target intent `Intent_name` is not updatable. Please check that the intent has been configured for updates.",
>           "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
>       }
>   }

Comment: Have you checked that the intent has been configured for updates?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

For me the solution was to add the "locale" field in the target.

```
let notification = {
    userNotification: {
        title: 'titolo',
    },
    target: {
        userId: userId,
        intent: intent,
        locale: 'it',
    }
};
```

Source: [Target](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#target)